# gradle: Facing exception, when tried to use gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, gulp

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app-android'.
>
> > Could not find method complile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1] on project ':app-android'.

Trying to compile using command line, but fails with the above exception.
Unable to figure out the problem from the simlar questions asked earlier.
Please help me.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.0 LTS

Comment: Please post build.gradle file you're trying to run

Comment: Pls ignore. Finally figured out after a sound sleep. Misspelt complile instead of compile. Thanks